# Template metaprogramming recursive evaluation

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct rm_const_volatile {
    using type = T;
};

// Call this (partial)specialization as "1"
template<typename T>
struct rm_const_volatile<const T> {
    // remove topmost const and recurse on T
    using type = typename rm_const_volatile<T>::type;
};

// Call this (partial)specialization as "2"
template<typename T>
struct rm_const_volatile<volatile T> {
    // remove topmost volatile and recurse on T
    using type = typename rm_const_volatile<T>::type;  
};
```

I had defined the remove const volatile qualifier template meta-program as above.

Logically, when I write `rm_const_volatile<const volatile int>`, my expectation is that compiler will evaluate in the following order:

Case 1:

- `rm_const_volatile<const volatile int>`
- [Use specialization 1]-> `rm_const_volatile<volatile int>`
- [Use specialization 2]-> `rm_const_volatile<int>`
- [Use general template]-> `int` (final result).

Case 2:

- `rm_const_volatile<volatile const int>`
- [Use specialization 2]-> `rm_const_volatile<const int>`
- [Use specialization 1]-> `rm_const_volatile<int>`
- [Use general template]-> `int` (final result).

So in my view above template specialization and general definition suffices to remove any const volatile qualifiers.

Cut the actual behavior errors out as ambiguous template instantiation.

```
// In main() below two calls are present (refer cpp.sh link below mentioned for full code)

----
   std::cout << "Is volatile const int integral type with rm_const_volatile: " << is_integral<rm_const_volatile<volatile const int>::type>::value << std::endl;
   
   std::cout << "Is const volatile int integral type with rm_const_volatile: " << is_integral<rm_const_volatile<const volatile int>::type>::value << std::endl;

-------

 In function 'int main()':
54:132: error: ambiguous class template instantiation for 'struct rm_const_volatile<const volatile int>'
26:8: error: candidates are: struct rm_const_volatile<const T>
31:8: error:                 struct rm_const_volatile<volatile T>
54:95: error: incomplete type 'rm_const_volatile<const volatile int>' used in nested name specifier
54:95: error: incomplete type 'rm_const_volatile<const volatile int>' used in nested name specifier
54:138: error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

When I add following template specialization, everything works fine.

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct rm_const_volatile<const volatile T> {
    using type = T;  
};
```

Please refer to this link for the full code.

I would like to know why the compiler reports template instantiation as ambiguous, when clearly it can chop off the top most qualifier and recursively instantiate to the final result as I have mentioned in the case 1 & 2 above.

Highly appreciate your valuable inputs and my sincere thanks for your time.

Comment: What is your definition of "top most qualifier"?  Does that mean the qualifier that happens to be mentioned first in the code?

Comment: `const volatile T` and `volatile const T` **are** the same type. [Demo with int](https://godbolt.org/z/7qMrGMMhn).

Comment: @DrewDormann yes the qualifier that appears first in cv qualified type passed to rm_const_volatile meta-program.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes agreed they are same. The users of the rm_const_volatile could pass in either form of the type (const volatile T or volatile const T> and expect the return type 'T'

Comment: Assume you do different things for `const T` and `volatile T`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I do not understand your comment "Assume you do different things for const T and volatile T".  Would you rephrase what you are trying to convey?

Comment: Assume `template<typename T> struct foo<const T> { using type = int; }; template<typename T> struct foo<volatile T> { using type = char; };`, we have `std::is_same_v<const volatile T, volatile const T>`, but we won't have `std::is_same_v<typename foo<const volatile T>::type, typename foo<volatile const T>::type>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know why the compiler reports template instantiation as ambiguous

C++ considers `const volatile int` and `volatile const int` to be the same type.  They are interchangable **and mean the same thing**.

Some other ways to spell this one type:

- `int const volatile`
- `int volatile const`
- `const int volatile`
- `volatile int const`

That said, C++ will never change overload rules based on the way you *choose to spell* a particular type.

Therefore, the template specializations `<const T>` and `<volatile T>` are both equally specialized for `<const volatile int>`.  Neither qualifier takes priority over the other.

Comment: "the template specializations <const T> and <volatile T> are both equally specialized for <const volatile int>" - So, the instantiation was ambiguous.

Comment: But for a template meta-program writer, the order of qualifier declaration is the key to define meta-program like std::remove_cv_t. Say if you would like to write your own meta-program like std::remove_cv_t considering all possible order of qualifier part of the type, how would write one? Do we need to know compiler internals' to implement to roll out our own version?

Comment: @NeelakantanK I think everyone is failing to successfully convey that **qualifiers do not have an order**.  See "Possible implementation" for [`std::remove_cv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv#Possible_implementation)

Comment: "I think everyone is failing to successfully convey that qualifiers do not have an order. " Agreed. A proof would go a long way. I have convinced myself with a test template meta-program. Sharing the link for the benefit of others. http://cpp.sh/3nqqr